# In Windows Chrome, how can I reduce the scroll wheel speed, including in the developer tools?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling, scroll-wheel

Running Windows 7 and Chrome. For some reason, one tick of my scroll wheel jumps something like 20-30 lines at one time, far too fast. It's most annoying when trying to use the developer tools, especially the Javascript console and the element inspector.

The Windows setting for scroll wheel speed does have an effect, but to make it reasonable in Chrome I have to set it to its minimum value, and even then Chrome is still too fast, and of course then every other application is too slow.

There are extensions that change the scroll wheel behavior in Chrome, but they don't have any effect on the developer tools, so it's no good to me in this case.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this happen system level? If it does, check control panel > mouse > wheel tab > change the number of lines.

Comment: @shinjijai No, other applications scroll the right amount, which is why changing the system setting isn't a viable solution.

Comment: if you go incognito, does it still scrool 20-30 lines at a time? if not, perhaps one of your extension is causing this (unless you allow some extensions to run in incognito).

Comment: I have the exact same problem - Chrome doesnt respect Window's mousewheel scrolling speed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running KatMouse?  I was having this same problem recently, but I found that Chrome scrolled naturally when I turned off KatMouse.

Setting KatMouse to ignore chrome.exe didn't have any effect, but setting special handling for the Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND class let KatMouse play nice with Chrome.  I used these instructions from http://eng.raneri.it/blog/2009/09/29/google-chrome-how-to-fix-the-fast-scroll-issue/ .  First, right click on the KatMouse icon and choose Settings.

> Then, switch to “Classes” tab and start Google Chrome: drag and drop
>   the KatMouse “target” icon to the main section of Chrome windows (the
>   one where web sites are rendered); you’ll see a new item named
>   “Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND” in the KatMouse list: double click it
>   and choose “Custom scroll”, then set it to “1” and confirm with OK.

This worked for both the page content and the element inspector.

Comment: THANK YOU! It's been driving me bonkers! You resolved 2 of my issues. I had no idea it was a katmouse issue that was causing the fast scroll & my middle click acting strangely. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after a bit of research, I learned that various mouse softwares have this issue. Mine was fine until I recently updated Chrome, and then went back to being too fast. So I disconnected my mouse and reconnected it. My computer updated (windows 7) the mouse software automatically and then the scroll speed returned to normal. If your system automatically updates Chrome, then you may just need to re-boot or update your mouse software after the update, whatever brand of mouse it is. Mine is a Microsoft wireless USB Mouse.